# Using CANbus cable for RS-485

Tags: can, rs485, modbus

I have a question regarding an application with a Modbus RTU network.

I would like to know if it's possible to use a CANbus cable instead of an RS-485 cable? Here is a picture of the cable:

[image: Photo of CANbus cable]

Comment: you definetly can use it. Z = 120 Ω. You have to use bus termination on each side of the bus - 120 Ohm at the RS485 too.

Comment: @TomKuschel Stop answering questions in the _comment_ section.

Comment: That's not a CAN bus cable though...? This is: https://www.helukabel.com/en/products/helukabel-reg-bus-cables-can-bus-0-22-mm-sup2-nbsp-2x2xx0.22-pvc-pair-stranded-flexible-opc-DNT_82509.html

Comment: Anyway, CAN or RS-485, you must have a signal ground. If you pick a cable with just 2 signals, then you need to consider just how the different nodes will be grounded. Using some raw supply or chassis ground as reference is ___bad___.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes this cable is suitable dependig on application. This cable can only carry the bus, no power.